# why the coding cannot print showLL function?

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list, undefined-behavior, function-definition

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<assert.h>

typedef struct node { 
  int data; 
  struct node *next; 
} NodeT;


NodeT *makeNode();
NodeT *joinLL();
void showLL();
void freeLL();
int a;

int main(void){
   
   NodeT *head;
   printf("Enter an integer:");
   while (scanf("%d", &a)){
       joinLL(head, &a);
       printf("Enter an integer:");
   }
  showLL(head);
  if(scanf("%d", &a)!=1){
      printf("Done.\n");
    }
        

    freeLL(head);

    return 0;
    
}


//creat a new node
NodeT *makeNode(int v) { 
  NodeT *new = malloc(sizeof(NodeT)); 
  assert(new != NULL); 
  new->data = v; // initialise data
  new->next = NULL; // initialise link to next node
  return new; // return pointer to new node
}


//append a new element with data v at the end of list.
NodeT *joinLL(NodeT *head, int v){
    NodeT *insert=makeNode(v);
    insert -> next = NULL;  

    if (head==NULL){
        head = insert;  
    }
    else{
        NodeT *temp;
        temp=head;
        while (temp->next != NULL){
        temp=temp->next;
       }
        temp->next=insert;
    }
    return insert;
    }
     

    

void showLL(NodeT *head) {

    //iterate the entire linked list and print the data
   NodeT *p;

   for (p = head; p!=NULL; p = p->next) {
        int elements= p->data;
        printf("Done. List is %d-->", elements);
   }
}


void freeLL(NodeT *head) {
   NodeT *p, *temp;

   p = head;
   while (p != NULL) {
      temp = p->next;
      free(p);
      p = temp;
   }
}
```

I have tried many times to run the function and find out that showLL function cannot be printed. Something wrong with my code?? I think there is something related to pointer or something very basic, but I' m new in c.Also, I would like to enter a non-numeric character, then print Done. Can I write scanf("%d", &a)!=1? ?

Comment: Your program has undefined behavior because the pointer head declared like NodeT *head; is not initialized.

Comment: `void showLL();` Please don't do that. That declares the `showLL` function as a function that takes an unknown number of arguments or unknown type. Use the actual ad full declaration instead, i.e. `void showLL(NodeT *head);`. That will allow the compiler to give more meaningful errors if you call it with the wrong arguments. Also, for functions taking no argument, please use the `void` argument explicitly.

Comment: Also note that I can easily make `while (scanf("%d", &a))` an infinite loop, by pressing the end-of-file sequence. For end of file, or errors in general, the `scanf` function returns `EOF` which is equal to `-1` and therefore not zero. Only zero is false, everything else, including negative numbers, are true.

Comment: Coming back to the argument in the declarations, this is actually an issue here! You call `joinLL(head, &a)` which is telling the compiler that `joinLL` is really `NodeT *joinLL(NodeT *, int *)` which is not true when you look at the definition later. The compiler should be issuing warnings or errors about that. And if you only get warnings, then treat all warnings as errors.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least three serious problems with your code.

The first one is that the pointer head is not initialized.

```
NodeT *head;
```

The second one is that the function `joinLL` returns either a pointer to the head node or a pointer to the inserted node that makes the function interface confusing.

Also the function is called incorrectly

```
joinLL(head, &a);
             ^^^
```

The function expects the second argument of the type `int` instead of `int *`.

As the defined list is a singly-linked list then it is more logically consistent and efficient to add new nodes to the beginning of the list. In this case using your approach the function can look very simple the following way

```
NodeT * joinLL( NodeT *head, int v )
{
    NodeT *insert = makeNode( v );
    insert -> next = head;  

    return insert;
}
```

And the third one is that in main in this while loop

```
while (scanf("%d", &a)){
    joinLL(head, &a);
    printf("Enter an integer:");
}
```

the pointer to the head node is not changed.

Using your function implementation then in main you should write

```
NodeT *head = NULL;
NodeT *tail = NULL;

printf("Enter an integer:");
while (scanf("%d", &a) == 1 ){
    tail = joinLL(tail, &a);
    if ( head == NULL ) head = tail;
    printf("Enter an integer:");
}
```

Pay attention to that this function declarations without prototypes

```
NodeT *makeNode();
NodeT *joinLL();
void showLL();
void freeLL();
```

makes the code unsafe. For example in the C23 Standard such declarations are forbidden.